# Actualizar DIV con Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo este código para actualizar `div` cada tiempo, pero siento que hace mucho esfuerzo a mi servidor.

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
function refreshDivs(divid,secs,url)
{

// define our vars
var divid,secs,url,fetch_unix_timestamp;
// The XMLHttpRequest object

var xmlHttp;
try{
xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
}
catch (e){
try{
xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
}
catch (e){
try{
xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
catch (e){
alert("Tu explorador no soporta AJAX.");
return false;
}
}
}

// Timestamp para evitar que se cachee el array GET

fetch_unix_timestamp = function()
{
return parseInt(new Date().getTime().toString().substring(0, 10))
}

var timestamp = fetch_unix_timestamp();
var nocacheurl = url+"?t="+timestamp;

// the ajax call
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
setTimeout(function(){refreshDivs(divid,secs,url);},secs*1000);
}
}
xmlHttp.open("GET",nocacheurl,true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}

// LLamamos las funciones con los repectivos parametros de los DIVs que queremos refrescar.
window.onload = function startrefresh(){
refreshDivs('div1',10,'ejemplo1.php');
refreshDivs('div2',10,'ejemplo2.php');
}
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Y como sabes que estas saturando el servidor? Digo podrias optar por refrescar en otro evento como en un click o no se, depende de que es lo que estes haciendo.

Comment: Estoy creando notificaciones, algo sencillo pero lo que pasa es que como tengo otras peticiones vía ajax, se satura la parte de notificaciones me refiero al código.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con Jquery.
Algo como esto.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var refrescarid = setInterval(function() {
            $("#div1").load("url que quieres cargar")
            .error(function() { alert("Error"); });
        }, 1000); // Tiempo
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });              
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias, lo voy a probar y te aviso :)

Comment: Espero te sirva.